# Conditions necessary to distribute a derivative across an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a function that's defined in terms of a definite integral on a constant domain, so the Fundemental Theorem of calculus doesn't seem to apply.  I *think* I just distribute the derivative across the integral sign,  but I'm not 100% certain.

The function is $I(\epsilon)=\int _\Omega \nabla(u+\epsilon v)\cdot \nabla (u+\epsilon v)dV $ with $\epsilon \in \mathbb R$,  $u\in C^2(\overline \Omega),v\in C_0^\infty (\Omega)$.

So, are there any conditions to be met to say that $I'(\epsilon)=\int _\Omega \frac d {d\epsilon} \big(\nabla(u+\epsilon v)\cdot \nabla (u+\epsilon v)\big)dV$?

Comment: There are conditions which allow such an interchange of integral and derivative. But in your case, it is **much** easier, to just expand the term defining $I(\epsilon)$ before you try to take the derivative. You can pull all occurences of $\epsilon$ out of the integral.

Comment: @PhoemueX Doh,  you're right.  If you want to convert that to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are general criteria (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) which allow to interchange a derivative and an integral. This is known as **differentiation under the integral**.

In this case, however, this is not necessary. Your integral is of the form
$$
\int (f+\epsilon g)(f+\epsilon g)\,dx = \int f^2\,dx + 2\epsilon \int fg \,dx +\epsilon^2 \int g^2\,dx
$$
for suitable $f,g$. Note that this is a **polynomial** in $\epsilon$ (with integrals as coefficients), so that taking the derivative is straightforward.

Comment: I edited out the .m for the mobile page in your link. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: Yep, as soon as you mentioned the comment, I realized I could factor out the epsilon...since that's what I already had gotten when I worked it out as if I could interchange the derivative.  Thanks :)